# The inverse function of $\ln(x + 1)$

Tags: functions, logarithms, inverse-function

The following problems says:

Given the function $ f : A \rightarrow B$, determine the sets $A$ and $B$ for which $ y = \ln(x + 1)$ has an inverse.

How can I solve it, and what are the key aspects to analyze ?

Comment: What's the maximal domain of $\ln(x+1)$? Is it one-to-one on that whole domain? If so, then $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the range. If not, find a set $C$ so that the restriction to $C$ is one-to-one, and then $C$ is the desired $A$ (and $B$ should still be the whole range).

Comment: A key aspect to analyse is if for a given $b$, there is a **single** $a$ s.t. $y(a)=b$. Try writing it down.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f $ is defined if $A=(-1,+\infty) .$

$$f'(x)=\frac {1}{1+x} .$$

$f $ is continuous and strictly increasing at $A $.

$f $ is then a bijection from $A $ to
$$f (A)=(\lim_{x\to -1^+}f (x),\lim_{x\to +\infty}f (x))$$
$$=(-\infty,+\infty)=\mathbb R =B. $$

> remark

You can take for $A $ any subset $C $ of $(-1,+\infty) $ and $B=f (C) $.

Answer (score 0):

This function is defined in $(-1,+\infty)$

$\ln{(x+1)}=\ln{(y+1)} \Rightarrow  e^{\ln{(x+1)}}=e^{\ln{(y+1)}} \Rightarrow x+1=y+1 \Rightarrow x=y$.
Thus $f$ is an injection.

Now $y=\ln{(x+1)} \Rightarrow  e^y-1=x$

Therefore $f^{-1}(x)=e^x-1$

The range of $f$ by taking limits is the whole real line.